# Play and stop music when press and release a button

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm coding a music app with buttons. I want to make music sound while a button is pressed but stop it when it's released. Also I want to play the music in a constant loop without separation between loop times. 
Now when I press the button music starts to play but when I release the button it stills playing untill the end of the file.

This is the code:

```
    @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            MediaPlayer do2n = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_leg);
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(v.getId()==R.id.dor){
                   do2n.start();
                }
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(v.getId()==R.id.dor){
                    if (do2n != null)
                        do2n.release();
                }
            }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: try adding `do2n.stop()` in the Action_UP block of your code see if it helps

Comment: @kabuto178 that won't work, the `MediaPlayer` is created in the method. It needs to be created outside the method so that both `ACTION` events can start and stop the same `MediaPlayer` instance, just as @gunar has discussed.

Comment: yup i noticed now Dan, was not thinking he actually declared the media player there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have actually created 2 instances of MediaPlayer since `onTouch` is called twice: once for key down and once for key up. So the first time you're creating the player and then you lose the reference. The second time `onTouch` is called, for `ACTION_UP` you're creating a new `MediaPlayer` object, but that object is a different one than the previous created with `ACTION_DOWN` so calling `stop` on this newly created object has no effect.

So you could instantiate the player as a class variable. Something like below:

```
private MediaPlayer do2n;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.dor) {
            do2n = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_leg);
            do2n.start();
        }
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.dor) {
            if (do2n != null) {
                do2n.stop();
                do2n.release();
                do2n = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    /**
     * The activity may be destroyed if you receive a long phone call while
     * keeping the button pressed so it's safe to do this
     */
    if (do2n != null) {
        do2n.stop();
        do2n.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I initiallizated the variable before the onCreate and I added the do2n = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_leg); inside the onCreate.

Comment: Now it doesn't work. Now I don't even hear the music. This doesn't work. Please help me

Comment: ... and you need to remove `MediaPlayer do2n = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.do_leg);` from `onTouch`

Comment: Does Logcat report anything?

Comment: 12-05 22:48:13.090    3985-3985/com.gatgdev.rhenium E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)
            at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop(MediaPlayer.java:1062)
            at com.gatgdev.rhenium.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:104)

Comment: Ok, you made me curious :) ... trying to reproduce the problem. Will get back later on this

Comment: I'll wait for your message

Comment: @Genis: Sorry for the delay, I am short with memory, but made a sample app and was able to reproduce the problem, check my updated answer